# How to write logs to azure blob storage using managed identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, azure-blob-storage, nlog, azure-managed-identity

I have asp.net core 3.1 webapp which is able to access Azure blob storage using managed identity.
Now I'm trying to get NLOG to connect using managed identity as well (it works with storage access key right now) but I can only find an option that works if it writes logs to an SQL DB with NLog.Extensions.AzureAccessToken or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0.0.

Does any logger have the ability to connect to azure blob storage using managed identity? or should I just write the logs in SQL DB instead of blobs.

I also understand that I can store the connection string in keyvault and use managed identity to retrieve it but I'd much rather find a direct way..

Comment: For writing to blob-target: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/ - [Docs](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md)

Comment: For writing to data-tables: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureDataTables/ - [Docs](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureDataTables/README.md)

Comment: For writing to sql-db with managed identity. Then you can use [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-default-authentication) in ConnectionString. Or you can make use of https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage together with NLog DatabaseTarget - [Docs](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureAccessToken/README.md)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. I am currently writing logs using NLOG to azure blob storage. I am unable to find a way to do it with managed identity for NLOG to write in Azure blob storage. I did find documentation on how to use managed identity to connect to SQL DB. 
My question is: Is there a way to use NLOG (or any other logger) and managed identity to write logs in azure blob storage?

Comment: When you specify `serviceUri`-option for blob-target (Ex. `"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"`), then it will use Managed Identity acquired from AzureServiceTokenProvider. See [Docs](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md)

Comment: wow that was easy.. lol.
Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/) will activate use of Managed Identity, when specifying the `serviceUri`-option (Ex. `"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"`).

See also: [Docs](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md)